# Execute bundle command line

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony4

I created a small symfony4 bundle to manage Mysql database backup.

I created a [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/fpasquer/symfony-backup-bundle) folder to implement it easily.

after install, my package path is:

```
webDirectory\vendor\fpasquer\symfony-backup-bundle\BackupSymfonyBundle.php
```

I'm able to use every class from this bundle excepted commands.

This is one command:

```
<?php

namespace Fpasquer\BackupSymfony\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class BackupExportCommand extends AbstractBackup
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'Fpasquer:BackupSymfony:extract';

    ...
}
```

When I run it :

> php bin/console Fpasquer:BackupSymfony:extract

I get this exception:

> There are no commands defined in the "Fpasquer:BackupSymfony" namespace.

I'm sure my bundle is installed correctly because in my app:controller I'm able to use **DependencyInjection** from this bundle

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: The first thing that is wrong is expecting people to click on random internet images just to see an error message.  The second thing is that you probably need to update the psr4 section of composer.json.  Plenty of examples on how to do this.

Comment: Did you name your command 'BackupBundle:import' or just 'import'?

Comment: how did you define your command?

Comment: Does AbstractBundle extend the Symfony Command?  If so then the problem is that your bundle is not registering commands as services.  As a rule, the autowire magic available at the application level is not used in bundles.  You will probably need a [bundle extension](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/bundles/extension.html) as well as a bundle services file.  And check the console command docs to see how to register a command as a service.

Comment: Thank you @cerad I fixed it with your link

Comment: If you want other people to use your project, I'd highly recommend to use some more verbose commit messages and check the code before commiting it. This helps to build up reputation